# Send ByteArray to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, arrays

How to send a jpg image as `ByteArray` from as3 to javascript? And how to convert `ByteArray` to image in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript and DOM implementations of current web browsers don't really have good mechanisms for doing this sort of thing.

Your best bet is to have your AS3 return a DATA protocol URI with a base64-encoded version of the image. Modern browsers (IE8+, FF2+, etc) will accept a DATA URI as the SRC of an IMG tag and will render the image contained therein.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

You'll have to have a AS3 expert explain how to turn an byte-array into a base64-encoded string, but it cannot be that hard.

Comment: Indeed, that won't work in older browser versions. Without using a DATA URI, there's no other way to do this with the DOM itself.

Comment: For the record, the way to do the conversion is: Take your DisplayObject (Sprite/MovieClip/whatever), convert it to BitmapData (myBitmapData.draw(mySprite);), convert that to a PNG using adobe's AS3CoreLib (myByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(myBitmapData);), convert that to Base64 using Flex's Base64Encoder (myBase64Encoder.encodeBytes(myByteArray);), then export that to some Javascript function using ExternalInterface.

Answer (score 4):

Take your `DisplayObject` (`Sprite`/`MovieClip`/whatever) and convert it to a BitmapData:

```
myBitmapData.draw(mySprite);
```

Convert that to a PNG using adobe's [AS3CoreLib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/)

```
myByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(myBitmapData);
```

Convert that to Base64 using Flex's [Base64Encoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html):

```
myBase64Encoder.encodeBytes(myByteArray);
```

Then [export actionscript variables to Javascript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7fe8.html) using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Comment: after more than 3 years... and someone else found this post very useful !! thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in this class that does that:

https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/utils/DisplayObjectUtils.as

calling

```
var data:String = DisplayObjectUtils.getBase64ImageDataString();
```

will return this string:

```
data:image/png;base64,...
```

You then set the src of an img in html to that value.